# unable to install openssh-server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, apt-get

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (64-bit) from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and am now unable to install openssh-server. Here's what happens when I try:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that ytou have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client(= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1) but 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
        Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does this help http://askubuntu.com/questions/546983/ssh-installation-errors

Comment: It does - thanks! I'd vote to mark this as a duplicate but since that's a different site idk...